# LEFT OUTER JOIN behaving as CROSS JOIN in SPARK SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Apache Spark 1.6.1, and am trying to perform a simple left outer join between two tables. One of these tables are loaded from an HDFS folder directly, and the other by directly querying a Hive table.
This is what I have done:

```
data = sqlContext.read.format("parquet").option("basePath","/path_to_folder").load("path_to_folder/partition_date=20170501

print data.count()

data2 = sqlContext.sql("select * from hive_table")

print data2.count()
join5 = data.join(data2,data["session_id"] == data2["key"],"left_outer")

print join5.count()
```

The first two counts return the correct count number (around 2 million)
But the count after the join, returns around 2 billion.

In a left join, I should never have more records than the table on the left side. I assume this join is behaving like a cross join.
 How is this possible? 
 Thank you.

Comment: 2 million * 2 million = 4 trillion (in US terminology).  The `left join` is not acting like a `cross join`.

Comment: Where there are no matching rows in the second table you'll get only one row, but if there are multiple matching rows in the second table then you'll get a row for each match ... not knowing your data it's difficult to say more!

Comment: @SteveLovell. thank you so much. That actually made me think that if I apply a DISTINCT to the second table it might solve my problem, and it did! There are no repeated rows so what you mentioned doesn't happen anymore. :) Thank you so much